# How to remove unicode Hex character in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

In My Javascript code which is given below, I am going to multiply two variables. It gives **NaN** as a result of multiplication now.

I alerted the two variables which are going to be multiplied. One variable is an integer. But another variable contains **rupee symbol** (&#x20B9) with a decimal value. I need to remove this symbol from this variable.

I have tried the below code to remove the unicode characters from the variable.

```
price_per_day = price_per_day.replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]/g, '');
```

But it is showing **NaN** after multiplication.

```
total_days=10;
price_per_day = price_per_day.replace(/[\uE000-\uF8FF]/g, '');
var total_amount = parseFloat(price_per_day) * total_days;
```

Comment: So what exactly is `price_per_day`? Is it `5 &#x20B9;`, or is it `5 ₹`? Please give us some input values you're trying this on.

Comment: Likely `5 ₹ 50` or something

Comment: I got `&#x20B9; 50.99` when I alerted `price_per_day`. ie symbol first then amount

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing the symbol, extract the money

```js
var price = document.getElementById("price").innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9.,]/g,"");
alert(price)
```

```html
<span id="price">    &#x20B9; 50.99</span>
```